# Как установить restart policy через Dockerfile или Docker.DotNet

Tags: c#, docker

Мне нужно установить --restart unless-stopped Для моего Docker-контейнера.
Я использую Dockerfile для настройки контейнера например со следующим содержимым:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build-env
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY . ./
ENTRYPOINT ["asd", "proj.dll"]
```

И используя Docker.DotNet для запуска контейнеров приблизительно следующим кодом:

```cs
            container.StartContainerAsync(container.ID, null);
```

Как установить эту политику в этом случае? Возможно, я могу как-то использовать `ContainerStartParameters`?

Answer (score 0):

Через Dockerfile: никак. Это просто невозможно.

Через Docker.Dotnet можно следующим образом:

```cs
using Docker.DotNet;
using Docker.DotNet.Models;
using System;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dockerClient = new DockerClientConfiguration(new Uri("http://localhost:2375")).CreateClient();
        var createParameters = new CreateContainerParameters
        {
            Image = "ubuntu:latest",
            Cmd = new List<string> { "bash", "-c", "echo 'Hello World'" },
            HostConfig = new HostConfig
            {
                RestartPolicy = new RestartPolicy
                {
                    Name = "unless-stopped"
                }
            }
        };
        var response = await dockerClient.Containers.CreateContainerAsync(createParameters);
        await dockerClient.Containers.StartContainerAsync(response.ID, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Забавно, что я выяснил ответ, когда вопрос потерял актуальность =)